# Merging code from both side in android studio and remote side(Bit-bucket)

Tags: android, android-studio, merge, overriding, bitbucket

I'm using bitbucket for Android Project,  there is a change in the remote side and also there is a change in the code of Android Studio. My need is I have to keep code from both sides. first, I pull the remote code and it is saying that

> your local changes would be overwritten by merge.commit stash or revert them to proceed

after getting this error and doing the search on it, I fetch the code and rebase it, see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FETTR.png), it was asking for merging from left or right, whenever I merge from right it overrides the android studio code, in that condition what should be an approach for keeping android studio code as well remote code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now are in situation of **conflict** now. You have to `Resolve those` conflicts. To resolve those conflicts you can either use:

1. Any **tool/editor** (currently you are using Android Studio's inbuilt tool). Which you are finding bit confusing
2. OR **manually** go to each file and see what are your change you want to keep and what are the changes you got after pull from remote.

Comment: @farhana I always prefer `sourcetree` over Android Studio's version control tool. Try that hope you will find that easy.